# Angular ng-init: 'injecting data via server side scripting'

Tags: angularjs

From the Angular docs regarding ng-init:

> This directive can be abused to add unnecessary amounts of logic into
>   your templates. There are only a few appropriate uses of ngInit, such
>   as for aliasing special properties of ngRepeat, as seen in the demo
>   below; and for injecting data via server side scripting.

Could anyone explain the second use case:

> ...and for injecting data via server side scripting.

Specifically, would it be appropriate to use this directive to pass a value (e.g. model record id) from a Rails/PHP view to an Angular controller?

Other methods (using $location) seem unnecessarily complicated.

Comment: it's fairly simple, output of PHP is an HTML after all, so you can do something like: `'<div class="blah_blah_blah" ng-init="variable=<?php echo $json_data;?>"></div>`

Comment: it is not recommended to use ng-init. better to asign data into the $scope in the controller side

Answer (score 3):

Absolutely. If your PHP or Rails app generates a template, and it is convenient (and secure) to pass data from that app to your Angular app as an ng-init attribute value, that is a valid use case.

It is more useful to make an $http request if the data is a complex object and/or is likely to change (or be changed by the client app).