# how to loop through a JSON string using ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, angular-ui-grid

I have a scenario where I have to loop through the JSON string in template. I tried these 2 solutions but none of them are working properly:
1. Create a filter and pass it to ng-init:

```
< div ng-init="var1 = (COL_FIELD | FormatJson)"> 
<span ng-repeat="wut_detail in var1.wu_tester_detail"> {{wut_detail}}</span> </div>
```

Above filter converts the string to JSON object properly, but ng-init seems to be working abnormally it doesn't refreshes data properly on search.

Can anyone please help, how I can change the variable COL_FIELD to JSON object in the template without using ng-init.

Comment: Try attaching the JSON object to `$scope` then itterate through it with ng-repeat. check this topic for some reference [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21697695/angularjs-ng-repeat-access-key-and-value-from-json-array-object]

Comment: I cannot attach this to scope variable because there can be more than 5000 diff values for COL_FIELD. It will hung the browser

Comment: Ah I see, let me explore it a bit and i will get back to you.

Comment: Can I see page with complete son file?? Have you assigned `COL_FIELD` json value to a Scope variable?? Are you sure browser hanged that time??

Comment: You might be better of just making an `$http` request and save the result to `$scope` variable, i assume that after i read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34300193/angular-ng-init-injecting-data-via-server-side-scripting  and https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit.